# Validate a long type input

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to validate that a user only enters a long value as input (long bigger than 0 actually).

Compare and Range validator has DataTypeCheck for int values only. I was planning on using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.longvalidator.aspx) class in a CustomValidator but then I would need to write both, client and server side validation code.

Do you know of any other good way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try AJAX control FilteredTextBox

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

//Server side

```
function Boolean isValid(){
  try{
    long a=long.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    if(a>0) 
      return true;  
    return false;
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
    return false;  
  }
}
```

// Client Side

use parseLong() function instead of long.Parse(). Otherwise same as server side

Answer (score 1):

**Server Side**

```
Boolean IsLong(String input)
{
    Int64 r;
    return Int64.TryParse(input, out r);
}
```

**Client Side**

```
function isLong(field) {    
    field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');   
    return (field.value.length < 19);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegularExpressionValidator with an expression of

```
"^\d*[1-9]\d*$"
```

This will validate that it is any number of digits with at least one 1-9, (so greater than zero).